# Why does datafreme error after using GRfit for grouping?

Tags: r, drc

I saw error in R-script.

```
library(GRmetrics)
df <- read.csv("E:/Result 2023-1-19/KKU100.csv")
head(mydata) 
df1 <- na.omit(df)

drc_output = GRfit(df1, groupingVariables = c('cell_line','treatment'))
drc_output
```

and the error is :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "r2_GR", value = c(0.832500851136755,  : 
  replacement has 6 rows, data has 7
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

in other result I can get the GR-curve

```
drc_output = GRfit(mydata, groupingVariables = c('cell_line','treatment'))
drc_output
```

I will get the data like this:

```
drc_output
class: SummarizedExperiment 
dim: 19 5 
metadata(2): '' ''
assays(1): ''
rownames(19): ctrl_cell_doublings GR50 ... pval_rel_cell flat_fit_rel_cell
rowData names(2): Metric Description
colnames(5): SSP25 Afatinib SSP25 Evolimus SSP25 Lapatinib SSP25 Mubritinib SSP25
  Tuxobertinib
colData names(6): cell_line treatment ... experiment concentration_points
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will be much easier to diagnose your issue with a sample of your data. Please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to make your issue reproducible. Then run `dput(df)` and `dput(mydata)` and add the results to your question. Thanks